# Extract numbers from a text file and place them in another file

Tags: shell-script, osx

I have a text file whose contents looks like this:

```
{"result":"true","last":0.02094,"high":0.0213,"low":0.01682,"avg":0.01871,"sell":0.02094,"buy":0.02054,"vol_ltc":5145.8262,"vol_btc":96.29887,"rate_change_percentage":"23.47"}`
```

(This is data from an API)

I want it formatted so my program can read it, but I need to extract the numbers because some of the exchanges are formatted differently by the API, for example, this:

```
{"result":"true","last":"0.00000070","high":"0.00000073","low":"0.00000069","avg":"0.00000071","sell":"0.00000071","buy":"0.00000069","vol_doge":71072621.657,"vol_btc":50.64272,"rate_change_percentage":"0.00"}
```

(Difference: quotes around price values)
And I need something that looks like this:
(Using the first one)

```
0.02094
0.0213
0.01682
0.01871
0.02094
0.02054
5145.8262
96.29887
23.47
```

Alternatively something like this (again, using the first one)

```
last
0.02094
high
0.0213
low
0.01682
avg
0.01871
sell
0.02094
buy
0.02054
vol_ltc
5145.8262
vol_btc
96.29887
rate_change_percentage
23.47
```

If you need more examples of strings provided from the API, go to http://data.bter.com/api#tickers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the API returns JSON objects, I'd use a JSON parser for it, combined with sed and grep.

I've decided for [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), which is contained in the Ubuntu repo's, so it could be installed using `sudo apt-get install jq`; I don't know what distro you are using, so you'll have to find that by yourself if you want to use this solution.

```
jq ".[]" <filename> | sed s/\"//g | grep -P '^\d+(\.\d+)$'
```

Now, let me split this up:

1. `jq ".[]" <filename>` will print the value for each key in the map. This probably doesn't work with nested maps, though.
2. `sed s/\"//g` will strip the list of any quotation marks.
3. `grep -P '^\d+(\.\d+)?$'` will return those lines that consist of integer or decimal numbers only.

This command chain will print the result to stdout. To get it into a file, simply pipe the output into it:

```
jq ".[]" <filename> | sed s/\"//g | grep -P '^\d+(\.\d+)$' > <other_filename>
```

Comment: you can use the [tonumber](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tonumber) function: `jq '.[] | tonumber'`. That's all:)

Comment: That will output in scientific notation...

Comment: Good thing `brew` (homebrew) has lots of stuff that are in Ubuntu repos, because I'm on mac :P. There was a small syntax error in the last line of code you provided, it should have been `jq ".[]" <filename> | sed s/\"//g | grep -P '^\d+(\.\d+)$' > <other_filename>` (at least for me.) Thanks for posting this!

Comment: @the_Seppi When piping it to a file, it's missing the last value (percentage change).

Comment: Only when piping, but not when printing to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

here is a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/.*?(\d+\.\d+)/$1 . "\n"/eg' file1 > file2
```

Comment: It leaves garbage at the end: `"}`

Comment: ok, try this one: `perl -pe 's/.*?(\d+\.\d+)/$1 . "\n"/eg' file1 | egrep '^[0-9]' > file2`